# Estimate required memory for a process in R

Tags: r, memory

I have a dataframe with around 1.5 million participants and 245 variables. I need to run the following code:

```
data %>%
  gather(Measure, Result, -Var1, -Var2) %>%
  group(Var1, Var2, Measure) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(!is.na(Result))) %>%
  na.omit()
```

However, I don't have enough memory for this process and I get the "Cannot allocate vector of size 2.6 GB error".

I don't want to learn how to use packages that are created for handling large size data and instead I am planning on buying more RAM memory. However, I am not sure how much RAM should I buy. The missing 2.6 GB is maybe just for the part of the process and not for the whole process, right? Is there a way I can estimate how much memory does this process take so I can buy the required amount of RAM?

Comment: Check how big your dataframe is (`object.size()`). Your memory should be easily double that.

Comment: The dataframe is 3.11 GB. I have 8 GB of RAM and it's still not enough.

Comment: 3.11 * 2 is 6.22 - that means there is something like 1.5 left for the entire rest of the system. (unlikely). If you get 16GB you will be fine. However, I would really recommend taking just a little bit of time for thinking how to come with a coding solution to this problem.

Comment: If you are having one time problem, you increase memory.limit() adn if you have 64 bit windows, R will write on hard drive when it runs out of RAM. It will be a lot slower, but you can get an idea who much you actually need.